# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-1/\sqrt{n})^n$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n$$ converges.

I can't seem to apply the integral test and the root test is inconclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write it as

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}$$
Now the inner term goes towards $e^{-1}$, so you can bound the sum from above.